# File transfer from Ubuntu to Windows share and Android mobile

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

Is there any generalized method for file transfer from Ubuntu(c++ application) to Windows network share and Android mobile.

Currently I am using cifutils based on SMB to transfer file to Windows share using WIFI from my c++ application.

I want transfer file to Android mobile as well. I know SFTP can be used for this.

I want to have a generalized single method other than above two.

Any help shall really be appreciated.

Comment: Could you use an SD card (if supported by your PC)?

Comment: Thanks. I meant not manually using external media,  but from c++ applicatiin